# How to reference on deployment VS 2015 C++ Linker library dependencies?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, dependencies

Apologies if I get terminology wrong here I've not much experience with C++.

We have a C++ Project in Visual Studio 2015 which references a library via Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

This Library is dependent on ~10 other DLLs. What I'd like to understand is what is the right way to point to these dependencies following deployment of our C++ Project.

From what I can tell we have two options.

1) Add the dependencies to the Project and deploy them as part of the install to the application directory.

2) Somehow point the project on deployment to a location on server where the DLLs can be found, for example: C:\dependancyapp\api.

I've found that at debug time you can set -LIBPATH to point to other locations on the development machine for finding dependencies but I can't seem to see how this could be set to somewhere on a target server on deployment.

What is the right way to reference library dependencies in a C++ project when deploying?

NB: It might be worth pointing out that separate of our use of these DLLs for our project, they are installed as part of another application on the destination server.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the path of the directory where you store your dlls to system PATH (environment variable).